# When does a man become-Dwija(twice-born) , when he undegoes Upnayan or when he complete his Vedic studies?

Tags: vedas, upanayanam

In past men (possibly of three varnas) would undergo Upnayan and then would start the study of Vedas.

Now at what point does the man becomes dwija- when he undergoes upanyan and start to wear the sacred thread or when the completes the study of the Vedas ?

Comment: A man becomes a  dvija thru upanayana samskara , thereupon  undertakes study of vedas.There is another ceremony (samskara) known as samaavartana(something like convocation), performed upon completion of the study. Soon Vivaha is done , as there shouldn't be so much gap between samavartana and vivaha lest there is a problem of this man remaining  without an ashrama. I guess there is no samavartana for naishtika brahmachari , who opts to continue in gurukul, and may take up direct sanyaasa.