# Who is eligible to beome Naistik Brahmchari?

Tags: marriage, sex

I keep hearing the word Naistik brahmchari . Can anyone explain to me who is eligible to become Naistik Brahmchari ?

How to become Naistik Brahmchari ?

In which ancient scripture(s) , Naistik Brahmchari is mentioned ?

**Naistik Brahmchari** - A man who doesn't marry and practice lifelong celibacy.

Comment: Naistik ? Can you add English word too?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto The word is "naishtika brahmachari". I have found it at [multiple](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31663/how-do-naishtika-brahmacharis-and-smartha-sanyasis-repay-the-deva-and-pitru-debt?noredirect=1&lq=1) [places](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53702/when-does-a-man-become-dwijatwice-born-when-he-undegoes-upnayan-or-when-he-c?noredirect=1#comment165368_53702) on this forum. I think It means a man who is lifelong celibate and doesn't marry ( and practice celibacy) even after attaining 25 years of age

Comment: correct - any brahmachari who has completed his studies (around 16 or 20 or 25 years of age), and has his lust sense (kama) under control and does not wish to beget sons, can decide not to enter grihasthashram (wear 2nd janeu/poonol), and continue on as brahmacharis to learn vedas and skip directly to vanaprastha or sanyasa ashram.

Comment: @mar Can you give the source of this from scriptures , prefrebly from main scriptures.

Comment: https://www.celextel.org/mantras-and-rituals/smriti-mukta-phalam/6/ - this is from vaidyanatha deekshiteeyam - the canonical compliation followed by 99% brahmins in south india. search for naishtika in it.